# Generating months between two dates?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to fill in the missing months in a `SELECT` statement so I was planning on joining my table with another table that contains all months. How can I generate a table of months in a light-weight fashion?  For instance,

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP(Timewhen DATETIME, Value INT)

INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('2012-02-04', 4)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('2012-02-06', 4)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('2012-02-10', 4)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('2012-04-08', 4)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('2012-04-12', 4)

SELECT YEAR(Timewhen) EventYear, MONTH(Timewhen) EventMonth, SUM(Value) Total
FROM #TEMP
GROUP BY YEAR(Timewhen), MONTH(Timewhen)

DROP TABLE #TEMP
```

gives me:

```
EventYear   EventMonth  Total
2012               2    12
2012               4    8
```

But I need:

```
EventYear   EventMonth  Total
2012        2           12
2012        3           0
2012        4           8
```

Comment: Why do you care how the data is generated, i.e. what does "lightweight" mean? Hopefully you intend to create a permanent calendar table or numbers table that you can use in all queries, not just this one? Although all databases should have both those tables available, because they have so many uses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE @months     INT, 
        @firstmonth DATE;

SELECT 
    @months     = DATEDIFF(MONTH, MIN(Timewhen), MAX(Timewhen)) + 1, 
    @firstmonth = DATEADD(DAY, 1-DAY(MIN(Timewhen)), MIN(Timewhen))
FROM #temp;

;WITH m(rn) AS 
(
  SELECT TOP (@months) rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id])
  FROM sys.objects ORDER BY rn
),
x(d) AS 
(
  SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, rn-1, @firstmonth) FROM m
)
SELECT YEAR(x.d), MONTH(x.d), Total = SUM(COALESCE(t.Value, 0))
  FROM x 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN #temp AS t
  ON t.Timewhen >= x.d AND t.Timewhen < DATEADD(MONTH, 1, x.d)
  GROUP BY YEAR(x.d), MONTH(x.d);
```

Or a slightly less verbose version:

```
DECLARE @months     INT, 
        @firstmonth DATE;

SELECT 
    @months     = DATEDIFF(MONTH, MIN(Timewhen), MAX(Timewhen)) + 1, 
    @firstmonth = DATEADD(DAY, 1-DAY(MIN(Timewhen)), MIN(Timewhen))
FROM #temp;

;WITH x(y, m, s, e) AS 
(
  SELECT YEAR(dt), MONTH(dt), dt, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, dt) FROM 
  ( SELECT dt = DATEADD(MONTH, rn-1, @firstmonth) FROM 
    ( SELECT TOP (@months) rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id])
      FROM sys.objects ORDER BY rn
    ) AS z
  ) AS y
)
SELECT EventYear = x.y, EventMonth = x.m, Total = SUM(COALESCE(t.Value, 0))
  FROM x LEFT OUTER JOIN #temp AS t
  ON t.Timewhen >= x.s AND t.Timewhen < x.e
  GROUP BY x.y, x.m;
```

**Alternate solution using Calendar table:**

Create a Calendar table using instructions from [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20120413100220/http://web.archive.org/web/20070611150639/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/why-should-i-consider-using-an-auxiliary-calendar-table.html).

```
-- Script to create a calendar table

DROP TABLE dbo.Numbers
DROP TABLE dbo.Calendar
GO

-- Use this to determine the number in the next query
DECLARE @NUMDAYS int
SELECT @NUMDAYS = DATEDIFF(DAY, '20000101', '20291231')

CREATE TABLE dbo.Numbers 
( 
    Number INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
) 

WHILE COALESCE(SCOPE_IDENTITY(), 0) <= @NUMDAYS
BEGIN 
    INSERT dbo.Numbers DEFAULT VALUES 
END
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Calendar  
(  
    dt SMALLDATETIME NOT NULL 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,  

    isWeekday BIT, 
    isHoliday BIT,  
    Y SMALLINT,  
    FY SMALLINT,  
    Q TINYINT,  
    M TINYINT,  
    D TINYINT,  
    DW TINYINT, 
    monthname VARCHAR(9), 
    dayname VARCHAR(9), 
    W TINYINT ,
    HolidayDescription VARCHAR(32)
) 
GO



INSERT Calendar(dt) 
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, Number, '20000101') 
FROM dbo.Numbers 
--WHERE Number <= @NUMDAYS 
ORDER BY Number

GO

--SELECT * FROM Calendar

UPDATE dbo.Calendar SET 

    isWeekday = CASE  
        WHEN DATEPART(DW, dt) IN (1,7)  
        THEN 0 
        ELSE 1 END, 

    isHoliday = 0, 

    Y = YEAR(dt),  

    FY = YEAR(dt), 

    /* 
    -- if our fiscal year 
    -- starts on May 1st: 

    FY = CASE  
        WHEN MONTH(dt) < 5 
        THEN YEAR(dt)-1  
        ELSE YEAR(dt) END, 
    */ 

    Q = CASE 
        WHEN MONTH(dt) <= 3 THEN 1 
        WHEN MONTH(dt) <= 6 THEN 2 
        WHEN MONTH(dt) <= 9 THEN 3 
        ELSE 4 END,  

    M = MONTH(dt),  

    D = DAY(dt),  

    DW = DATEPART(DW, dt),  

    monthname = DATENAME(MONTH, dt),  

    dayname = DATENAME(DW, dt),  

    W = DATEPART(WK, dt)

GO
```

After creating a `Calendar` table, one can use the following to achieve this:

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP(Timewhen DATETIME, Value INT)

INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('2012-02-04', 4)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('2012-02-06', 4)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('2012-02-10', 4)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('2012-04-08', 4)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('2012-04-12', 4)

SELECT Y EventYear, M EventMonth, SUM(Value) Total
FROM #TEMP RIGHT OUTER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Y,M FROM dbo.dateRange('20120204', '20120412')) X
ON YEAR(Timewhen) = X.Y AND MONTH(Timewhen) = X.M
GROUP BY Y,M

DROP TABLE #TEMP
```

Comment: +1 Thank you for your time. I am accepting this one but I really liked the link you added to my question as a comment so I ended up using that instead.

Comment: @Legend thanks, if you can be more specific about which link and which code sample, I can add it to my answer, in case this answer outlives that site (I do not control it any more so I have no idea how long it will stay up and intact).

Comment: Yes. definitely. This was it: http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/why-should-i-consider-using-an-auxiliary-calendar-table.html After creating that table, I did a `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` to get the necessary result.

Comment: Added a solution that I used to your answer. Please feel free to modify it if you feel otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

Using SQL Server, I would do something like:

```
select dateadd(month, num, firstdate) as mon
from (select row_number() over (partition by NULL order by (select NULL)) as num
      from Information_Schema.Columns c
     ) n cross join
     (select cast('2001-01-01' as date) firstdate) const
```

This creates a bunch of months from the first date.  I'm just using the Columns table to allow me to generate a sequence.

Comment: I quite liked this answer due to its speed and simplicity, however I get the following error 'Adding a value to a 'date' column caused an overflow' - I can't quite find a way to get it to stop at a given date.

Comment: @Morvael . . . Just add a `where` clause with a maximum count . . . `where date < 1200`, say.

Comment: I change the SQL to get a list of dates, which should works with any database has `dateadd` (or similar) function ---- `select dateadd(day, num, firstdate) as mon
from (select row_number() over (partition by NULL order by (select NULL)) as num 
from ANY_TABLE_WITH_ENOUGH_ROWS c) n
,  (select cast('2001-01-01' as date) firstdate) const`

Answer (score 2):

You could declare a pair of endpoints and build the year/month list from the sys.messages table:

```
DECLARE @EventStart datetime='1/1/2001';
DECLARE @EventEnd datetime='12/31/2012';

SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(MONTH,@EventStart,@EventEnd)+1)
EventYear=DATEPART(YEAR,DATEADD(MONTH,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY message_id)-1,@EventStart))
, EventMonth=DATEPART(MONTH,DATEADD(MONTH,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY message_id)-1,@EventStart))
FROM sys.messages m;
```

Result:

```
EventYear   EventMonth
----------- -----------
2001        1
2001        2
2001        3
2001        4
2001        5
.
.
.
2012        7
2012        8
2012        9
2012        10
2012        11
2012        12
```

Answer (score 0):

---if you are using ssrs report or creating performance point dashboard , have problem to create

---month drop down for the current or previous calendar year, here is the T-SQL script for you.

```
DROP TABLE #Numbers
DROP TABLE #Calendar
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Use this to determine the number in the next query
DECLARE @NUMDAYS int
DECLARE @start_date DATETIME, @end_date DATETIME
DECLARE  @year VARCHAR(50)
declare @year_num AS VARCHAR(50)
SET @year_num = 'current' ----'previous'
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
  SET @start_date = CASE @year_num
    WHEN 'current' THEN DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
    WHEN 'previous' THEN DATEADD(yy, -1, DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
    ELSE DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
  END
  SET @end_date = CASE @year_num
    WHEN 'current' THEN GETDATE() ----DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, -1, GETDATE()), -1)
    WHEN 'previous' THEN DATEADD(YY, -1, DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, -1, GETDATE()), -1))
    ELSE DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, -1, GETDATE()), -1)
  END

  SET @year = CASE @year_num
    WHEN 'current' THEN YEAR(GETDATE())
    WHEN 'previous' THEN YEAR(DATEADD(yy, -1, GETDATE()))
    ELSE YEAR(GETDATE())
  END

SELECT @NUMDAYS = DATEDIFF(DAY, @start_date, @end_date )

CREATE TABLE #Numbers 
( 
Number INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
) 

WHILE COALESCE(SCOPE_IDENTITY(), 0) <= @NUMDAYS
BEGIN 
  INSERT #Numbers DEFAULT VALUES 
END

CREATE TABLE #Calendar  
(  
dt SMALLDATETIME NOT NULL 
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,  

Y SMALLINT,  
Q TINYINT,  
M TINYINT,  
monthname VARCHAR(9)
) 

INSERT #Calendar(dt) 
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, Number,  @start_date) 
FROM #Numbers 
WHERE Number <= @NUMDAYS 
ORDER BY Number

UPDATE #Calendar 
SET Y = YEAR(dt),  
    Q = CASE WHEN MONTH(dt) <= 3 THEN 1 
             WHEN MONTH(dt) <= 6 THEN 2 
             WHEN MONTH(dt) <= 9 THEN 3 
             ELSE 4 END,  
    M = MONTH(dt),  
    monthname = convert(varchar(3),datename(month,dt))----DATENAME(MONTH, dt) 

select distinct Y,M,monthname 
from #Calendar
WHERE Y = @year
order by  M
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MIN (to_date((TO_CHAR (Actual_Date, 'DD-MM-RRRR')),'dd-mm-rrrr')) F_DATE,
         MAX (to_date((TO_CHAR (Actual_Date, 'DD-MM-RRRR')),'dd-mm-rrrr')) T_DATE,
         TO_CHAR (Actual_Date, 'MM-RRRR') MONTH
    FROM (    SELECT TRUNC (TO_DATE (:P_FDATE, 'dd-mm-rrrr')) + LEVEL - 1
                        Actual_Date
                FROM (SELECT TRUNC (TO_DATE (:P_FDATE, 'dd-mm-rrrr'), 'MM') - 1
                                AS dt
                        FROM DUAL)
          CONNECT BY LEVEL <=
                        (  TO_DATE (:P_TDATE, 'dd-mm-rrrr')
                         - TRUNC (TO_DATE (:P_FDATE, 'dd-mm-rrrr'))
                         + 1))
GROUP BY TO_CHAR (Actual_Date, 'MM-RRRR')
ORDER BY 1;
```