# Get rolling 12 months data in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a requirement to get the data for rolling next 12 months. This comes with a special condition to show the months with blank data if data does not exist in the database. For example - If data exists only till Jan 2017 then the result query should show Feb 2017 also but with blank data.

Using below query I am able to get the data which exists. I don't want to add any loops to check which month is missing and add those months.

```
SELECT
        SiteCode
        ,CustomerName
        ,CalYear
        ,CalMonth
        ,CalDay
        , CONVERT(DATE,CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),CalYear)+'-'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),CalMonth)+'-'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),CalDay)) AS CalDate
        ,MachineDownTimes
        ,MaterialsDownTimes
        ,LineBalancingLost
        ,Others
FROM 
        dbo.ProcessBackend
WHERE CustomerName = 'ZAS' AND SiteCode = 'HU01'
        AND DATEFROMPARTS(CALYEAR, CALMONTH, CALDAY) 
        BETWEEN DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()), DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE()), 1) AND 
        DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(YEAR, (DATEADD(MONTH, 12, GETDATE()))), DATEPART(MONTH, (DATEADD(MONTH, 12, GETDATE()))), 1)
```

What would be the best option to achieve this in SQL or C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned, these are the steps to achieve your goals:

**1) create a months table**, since you want to display month data even if data is not present. You can choose something from [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10601683/generating-months-between-two-dates) - I have adapted the shortest and elegant solution from there:

```
declare @today DATE = GETDATE()
declare @thisMonth DATE = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@today), MONTH(@today), 1)
declare @startMonth DATE = DATEADD(month, -11, @thisMonth)

PRINT 'This month '; PRINT @thisMonth
PRINT 'Start month '; PRINT @startMonth

declare @monthInfo TABLE (BOM DATE)

insert into @monthInfo (BOM)
select top 11 dateadd(month, num, @startMonth) as mon
from (select row_number() over (order by (select 1)) as num
      from sys.columns c
     ) n cross join
     (select @startMonth firstdate) const

SELECT * FROM @monthInfo
```

The results is:

### BOM

```
2015-05-01  
2015-06-01  
2015-07-01  
2015-08-01  
2015-09-01  
2015-10-01  
2015-11-01  
2015-12-01  
2016-01-01  
2016-02-01  
2016-03-01
```

**2) create final query** by selecting from generated dates and your table

```
DECLARE @CustomerName VARCHAR(100) = 'ZAS'
DECLARE @SiteCode VARCHAR(32) = 'HU01'

;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT SiteCode, CustomerName, DATEFROMPARTS(CalYear, CalMonth, 1) AS CalMonth, 
        MachineDownTimes, MaterialsDownTimes, LineBalancingLost, Others
    FROM dbo.ProcessBackend
    WHERE CustomerName = @CustomerName  AND @SiteCode = @SiteCode 
)
SELECT @CustomerName, @SiteCode, M.BOM, 
    SUM(MachineDownTimes), SUM(MaterialsDownTimes), SUM(LineBalancingLost), SUM(Others)
FROM @monthInfo M 
    LEFT JOIN CTE ON CTE.CalMonth = M.BOM 
GROUP BY CTE.CustomerName, CTE.SiteCode, M.BOM
```

Answer (score 0):

1. **Create** default month table which included (Jan -> Dec).
2. **Union** default month table with your output table and **SUM** (those columns you can to show) these column:

   ```
       (MachineDownTimes
       ,MaterialsDownTimes
       ,LineBalancingLost
       ,Others)
   ```
3. Done.

Reference : [Fill empty dates in a matrix SSRS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35468564/fill-empty-dates-in-a-matrix-ssrs/35470738#35470738)